# Access Pass Through & Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to use a pass through query using an ODBC connection, however I need to further refine the SQL using another tables within the same Access database.

How do I reference the Access table? Access keeps thinking I am looking for a table via the ODBC connection rather than the database itself.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are trying to do to "refine the [pass-through query's] SQL using another tables within the same Access database". The short answer to "How do I reference [an] Access table [in a pass-through query]?" is that one doesn't normally do that, but there may be a workaround available depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You cannot reference any local objects in a pass through query - they are not visible to the remote server that is executing it. You can however use your "unrefined" pass through query as another object in a native Access query, joining it to other Access native tables and queries.

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a Linked Table in access, using the ODBC connection. Then, you just write a query against the Access database using whatever name you give your Linked Table, and the names of the access tables.

Be warned: if the linked table contains a large number of rows, Linked Tables can be very inefficient.